# Computing permanents when we are promised that the value of the permanent is large

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, quantum-computing

Suppose you are given an $n$ by $m$ real matrix (or even complex matrix) with orthonormal rows. ($m=poly(n)$, say $m=n^2$.) For an $n$-tuples of columns (with repetitions) from M we consider the corresponding $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$. Boson sampling is the sampling task to sample $n$-tuples of columns (with repetitions) according to the (absolute value) of the square of the permanent of $A$. Those values sum up to 1 when we introduce certain weights for minors with repeated columns.

Boson sampling can be performed efficiently by a quantum computer and even by a rather simple photonic system that represents a small fragment of quantum computation.

Boson Sampling was [extensively studied by Aaronson and Arkhipov](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3245) (around 2010) who proved that a polynomial-time algorithm for Boson Sampling would imply that the polynomial hierarchy collapses. Earlier, Boson Sampling was [introduced by Tishby and Troyansky](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjyu9Dzu9_3AhV2hP0HHW0cBesQFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.huji.ac.il%2Flabs%2Flearning%2FPapers%2Fperm.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0RgQCT-5Exe_Zl5iBmnCwB) (in 1996) and in their paper they asked the question if Boson Sampling can be used for efficiently computing permanents with quantum computers and are there fundamental differences in this respect between Boson Sampling based on permanents and Fermion Sampling based on determinants.

As noted already by Tishby and Troyansky using Boson Sampling to estimate the value of a permanent requires, in general, exponentially many samples. However, if the absolute value of the permanent is a constant or $1/poly(n)$ then quantum computers enable to approximate this value efficiently. My question is about the classical difficulty in this particular case. In this question we consider an $n$ by $n$ submatrix $A$ of $M$, and for simplicity assume that there are now repeated columns.

**Question 1**: What is known about the classical complexity of the question of estimating the (absolute) value of the permanent of an $n$ by $n$ submatrix $A$ of an orthogonal matrix $M$ if we are promised that the value of the permanent is larger than an absolute constant K. Or even for $K=1/poly(n)$.

An alternative way to think about this question is about the clssical difficulty to estimate
$|{\bf permanent} (A)|^2$ up to an additive small constant (or $1/poly(n)$) error.

**Question 2:** Suppose we are promised that the permanent of $A$ (in absolute value) is either exponentially small of larger than a constant (or $1/poly(n)$). Is there an efficient classical algorithm to tell between these options?

**Remark:** We can start from a $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$ such that the sum of absolute value squared in each row is between two constants (independent of $n$) smaller than 1, and ask the questions for $A$ without worrying about the larger matrix $M$.

Comment: For those reading quickly (as I did), the orthonormality of the rows implies that the permanent is bounded from above by $n!$ (maybe better bounds are possible).